# Extracting first available number and its following text from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to extract a dosage and unit of measure from a string.
A string can contain very similar patters, but I just need to extract the very first number in a string with a dosage that follows it.

For example:

> Pain Medication. 20 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) Therapy: IV PCA Adult /
>   Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, IV, Routine PCA Dose =
>   0.4 mg

I need to extract **20** as a dosage, and **"mg"** that follows it as a unit of measure in a Select statement.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING('Pain Medication. 20 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) Therapy: IV PCA Adult / Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, IV, Routine PCA Dose = 0.4 mg',PATINDEX('%[0-9]%','Pain Medication. 20 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) Therapy: IV PCA Adult / Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, IV, Routine PCA Dose = 0.4 mg'), 5) - If you toy around with it a little bit you can make  it so that it deals with any number of digits.

Comment: Take a look here:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/

Comment: Does "Pain Medication. " always precede the dosage you want? does a slash always follow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b6f6/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([dosage] varchar(144))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([dosage])
VALUES
    ('Pain Medication. 20 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) 
      Therapy: IV PCA Adult / Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, 
      IV, Routine PCA Dose = 0.4 mg')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT substring(dosage,
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',dosage),
                 PATINDEX('%/%',dosage)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',dosage)
                )
FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b6f6/5/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
|----------|
|    20 mg |
```

Answer (score 1):

--Schema

```
CREATE TABLE script
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     details varchar(200)
    );

INSERT INTO script
(details)
VALUES
('Pain Medication. 20 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) Therapy: IV PCA Adult / Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, IV, Routine PCA Dose = 0.4 mg'),
('Pain Medication. 300 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) Therapy: IV PCA Adult / Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, IV, Routine PCA Dose = 0.4 mg');
```

--Dosage

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(
SUBSTRING(
  details,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details), 
  (select (PATINDEX('%[/]%',details)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details)))), 
  0, PATINDEX('%[ ]%',SUBSTRING(
  details,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details), 
  (select (PATINDEX('%[/]%',details)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details)))))) as [Dosage]
 from script
```

-- Units

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(
SUBSTRING(
  details,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details), 
  (select (PATINDEX('%[/]%',details)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details)))), 
  PATINDEX('%[ ]%',SUBSTRING(
  details,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details), 
  (select (PATINDEX('%[/]%',details)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',details))))),
3) as [Units]
 from script
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e0b6/38

Answer (score 0):

Elegant answer already given but this can also be done without substring function using the LEFT and RIGHT functions.

```
DECLARE @Mytext AS VARCHAR(200)
SET @Mytext = 'Pain Medication. 20 mg/100 mL NS (0.2mg/mL) 
      Therapy: IV PCA Adult / Qualifier: Standard Continuous Rate = 0 mg/hr, 
      IV, Routine PCA Dose = 0.4 mg'

SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@Mytext, LEN(@Mytext) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Mytext)-1)), 
        PATINDEX('%/%',RIGHT(@Mytext, LEN(@Mytext) 
        - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Mytext)-1)-1)))
```

Result:

20 mg